# What events are depicted in these frescos from the "Shield of the Hidden Lord" DMsGuild module (which expands on the Descent into Avernus adventure)?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, lore, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus

There is an unofficial module on DMsGuild named ["Shield of the Hidden Lord"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/293544/Shield-of-the-Hidden-Lord) by M.T. Black - who is one of the writers on the official adventure *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*, so I assume its lore is correct.

Pages 7-8 of the "Shield of the Hidden Lord" PDF include the descriptions of 4 frescos on the walls of area T2. These paintings reportedly depict Gargauth (presumably different key aspects or events relating to Gargauth).

What events or aspects exactly are depicted in each of the following frescos?

> ***First Fresco.*** A handsome sage in amber robes sits on a throne with a pile of scrolls next to him. He is speaking to a group of kings and queens, who listen to him with interest and respect.

- I suppose this is just an illustration of Gargauth's charming
  abilities. Is that the only meaning?

> ***Second Fresco.*** The sage in amber robes looks at a city in the background. The city is burning, and soldiers fight in its streets. In the foreground are two snakes, twisted together.

- What city is depicted here?
- Who are the soldiers, and what organisations do they belong to? Why
  do they fight?
- What is the meaning of these snakes?

> ***Third Fresco.*** The sage in amber robes rides a blue dragon over a dark forest. In a clearing in the forest is a unicorn with a broken, twisted horn.

- I found this dragon's name: Rathguul. Is that right?
- Why is there a unicorn?
- A twisted horn is Gargauth's holy symbol. But the module says that
  Gargauth's holy symbol is a Knight of the Shield badge. What is right
  here?

> ***Fourth Fresco.*** The sage in amber robes wields a rapier and fights a shadowy figure in dark armor. The shadowy figure wears a jeweled gauntlet.

- Why a rapier?
- Who is the figure? Bhaal?

Comment: Your question says "But the module says that Gargauth's holy symbol is a Knight of the Shield badge." Could you clarify what you mean by this, or where you're seeing this? (The "Shield of the Hidden Lord" PDF actually seems to describe the Knights of the Shield organization's holy symbol as a "shield-shaped copper pendant" on multiple occasions, and doesn't mention Gargauth's holy symbol at all.)

Answer (score 6):

### We'll never know for sure, but your guesses are good

I actually reached out to M.T. Black himself, and he was super nice and responded within a day! This is what he has to share about what is depicted on those murals:

> It's nice to hear from you and I'm glad to see their is still interest in SotHL. I did the first draft of that adventure back in 2017, so I'm afraid I can't remember all the details. My intention was to put up the sorts of murals that you would find in a religious temple, and not all of them reflected actual canonical events. I think the guesses you listed above are probably pretty close.

> Sorry I can't be more help!

> cheers,
> MTB"

Given that this is from the original author, I am afraid that is the bottom of what we will learn about the events depicted.